# ASP.Net 5/MVC 6 how to retrieve SessionID

Tags: asp.net-core-mvc, httpcontext, sessionid

My solution directory has ASP.Net 4 web-forms project, that at present has all the development of my website.

The plan is migrate some of the existing front-end to ASP.Net5/MVC6 web application. And for that to happen, I have added ASP.NET 5 empty web application to the existing solution directory. The reason I have decided to use blank template is so that I can add all the required capabilities myself, and understand the flow better.

Capabilities like MVC, Session, Caching, Logging etc.

I have added MVC capabilities. And to add Session related capabilities I have followed the steps given in the below documentation,

https://docs.asp.net/en/latest/fundamentals/app-state.html#installing-and-configuring-session

After this, I am able to add the access the Session in my controller class. I can put some values in the session and can access it in view to verify Session is operating fine.

Both of my web applications (ASP.Net 4 and ASP.Net 5) would be running side by side, and I want to enable user to navigate back and forth with a single sign on. That effectively means, they to share same session.

And hence, I am looking for a way to access SessionID from the Session, so that I can check whether the value is same for both the websites, however there is no method that gives me SessionID...

[image]

Can someone explain why it is so and how to retrieve unique session identity?

Comment: `ISession` has an Id property, however much more will be required to have the session data shared between ASP.Net 4 and ASP.Net 5. In the latter, the session code is completely new and is built on top of a [distributed cache](https://docs.asp.net/en/latest/performance/caching/distributed.html)`. You will need to make sure both read/write from the same storage (like redis or sql server) and use the same cookie value, domain and path

Comment: Thank you for your inputs. However, I don't see ISession interface to have Id property. http://docs.asp.net/projects/api/en/latest/autoapi/Microsoft/AspNet/Http/Features/ISession

Comment: I see, it looks like it was added after RC1, see [github](https://github.com/aspnet/HttpAbstractions/blob/release/src/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.Features/ISession.cs)